# Using hash tables in racket

Tags: scheme, hashtable, racket

Im working on an Ngrams program and im having trouble filling out my hash table.
i want to write out a recursive function that will take the words and add them to the hash table. The way its supposed to work is  given the data set 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
the first entry in the hash table should have a key of 
[1 2] and the data should be 3.
The second entry should be:
[2 3] and its data should be 4 
 and continuing on until the end of the text file.

we are given a predefined function called readword that will simply return 1 word from the text. But im not sure how to make these calls overlap each other. The calls would look something like this if the data was hard coded in.

```
(hash-set! (list "1" "2") 3 
(hash-set! (list "2" "3") 4
```

2 calls that ive tried look like this

```
  (hash-set! Ngram-table(list((word1) (word2)) readword in))) 
  (hash-set! Ngram-table(append((cdr data) word1)) readword in)
```

apparently the in after readword is supposed to tell the computer 
that this is and input instead of an output or something like that.

How would I call this to make the data in the key of the hashtable overlap like this?
And what would the recursive call look like?

edit: also we are not allowed to use assigment statements in this program.

Comment: What happened when you made those calls?  Did you get an error message?  What was it?

Comment: Isn't `hash-set!` an assignment statement?  After all, it's _assigning_ a value to an entry in the hash table.

Comment: I havent gotten that working yet because im unsure how to use the hashtable I understand how the call to the hashtable works and that isnt the problem. What im having isues with is how exactly to call the hash table in order to get it to assign the data correctly.

Comment: You don't call the hash table, you call `hash-set!`, which takes a hash table an an argument.  It's [documented well](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html) in the Racket documentation.  Its signature is `(hash-set! hash key v)`, as I've described in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for the sake of testing, we'll define a `readword` procedure that returns successive words from a list.  (In this case, it's just a list of numbers, but that's not really important.)  You've already got one of these, but we need one to make the *rest* of the code work.  This uses an assignment (`set!`), but this isn't code that *you* actually need to write;  this is just to make the rest of this answer work.

```
(define words (list 1 2 3 4 5 6))

(define (readword)
  (cond 
    ((null? words) words)
    (else (let ((word (car words)))
            (set! words (cdr words))
            word))))
```

```
> (readword)
1
> (readword)
2
```

Now we can define the main function that creates, populates using `readword`, and returns a hash table.  `insert-words` has an internal helper function that assumes that two words have already been read, and so it only needs to read the next word.  Our `readword` function returns `()` when there are no more words to be read, so our helper function stops when `readword` returns `()` and simply returns `ngrams`.  Otherwise, `readword` returned a word, and we can add an entry to the hashtable with [`hash-set!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/hashtables.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._hash-set!%29%29) as in `(hash-set! ngrams (list w1 w2) w3)`.  After that, we call the helper function again, but with `w2` and `w3` as the previous two words for which a third is needed.

```
(define (insert-words)
  (define (insert-helper ngrams w1 w2)
    (let ((w3 (readword)))
      (cond
        ((null? w3) ngrams)
        (else 
         (hash-set! ngrams (list w1 w2) w3)
         (insert-helper ngrams w2 w3)))))
  (insert-helper (make-hash) (readword) (readword)))
```

```
> (insert-words)
'#hash(((1 2) . 3) ((3 4) . 5) ((4 5) . 6) ((2 3) . 4))
```

This kind of pattern with a helper function that performs the iteration is so common that Scheme and Racket support something called a *named let*.  Using a named let, this looks like the following.  I used the name `loop`, because this is essentially a loop, but the particular name doesn't matter.

```
(define (insert-words)
  (let loop ((ngrams (make-hash))
             (w1 (readword))
             (w2 (readword)))
    (let ((w3 (readword)))
      (cond
        ((null? w3) ngrams)
        (else 
         (hash-set! ngrams (list w1 w2) w3)
         (loop ngrams w2 w3))))))
```